# How to make option selected in jquery by Name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can i make the option selected in jquery by Name

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Est9D/58/)

Here is the script

```
<select name="zoom_cat[]" style="margin-left:15px;" id="contact_country">
    <option value=""  selected="selected">Nothing</option>

  <option value="0">Singam</option>
  <option value="1">Karadi</option>
  <option value="2">Poonai</option>
  <option value="3">Yaanai</option>
</select>
```

And here is the script

```
var myText = "Singam";
        $("#contact_country option:text=" + myText +"").prop("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains/) selector

```
$("#contact_country option:contains('" + myText +"')").prop("selected", "selected");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/54w5rq5m/)

---

Note: Using contains can return partial results, so it might be safer to iterate and find the element ex: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/54w5rq5m/2/

So

```
var myText = "Singam";
$("#contact_country option").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == myText) {
        $(this).prop("selected", true);
        //since element is found no need to iterate further
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/54w5rq5m/3/)

Comment: The script should be loaded before or after the option select ??

Comment: if it is in the dom ready handler does not matter.. else after

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on options for a complete match. Contains gives you also partial match.

```
$('#contact_country option').filter(function() {
                    return $.trim($(this).text()) === myText;
                }).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:contains()` instead of `:text`. Try with -

```
    var myText = "Singam";
    $("#contact_country option:contains(" + myText +")").attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="test" class="mytest">One</a>
```

Two
Three

Javascript:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
$.scrollTo = function(el, options){
    // To avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
    // to reference this class from internal events and functions.
    var base = this;

    // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
    base.$el = $(el);
    base.el = el;

    base.init = function(){
        base.options = $.extend({},$.scrollTo.defaultOptions, options);

        // Put your initialization code here
    };

    // On click
  base.$el.click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        alert("clicked!");
    });    

    // Run initializer
    base.init();
};

$.scrollTo.defaultOptions = {};

$.fn.scrollTo = function(options){
    return this.each(function(){
        (new $.scrollTo(this, options));
    });
};
```

})(jQuery, window, document);

//Initialize plugin
$('.mytest').scrollTo();

Thanks